# What's needed to enable JDBC or ODBC to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, odbc, rhel6, jdbc

I have a MySQL server on my [Scientific Linux 6.2](https://www.scientificlinux.org/) system. Right now I know how to create a new database, and set up users.

I need to setup [LibreOffice Base](https://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/) to connect to the MySQL server, via either ODBC or JDBC (ideally over SSL).

How do I do this? Do I need to install anything on the server to allow this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to maintain a machine if you use distribution official packages. There are official mysql connector packages in Red Hat Enterprise Linux so I guess they are part of scientific linux too.

```
yum install mysql-connector-java mysql-connector-odbc
```

wrt SSL, you can take a look at the official doc:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

All you need is MySQL using sockets and the appropriate connector (downloadable from the MySQL site). After that it's just a matter of configuring the DSN. If you have questions relating to that I suggest you first read the documentation and then ask over at SO if you're still stuck.